# Regular and Strong tween does not work?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
new Tween(Image1movieClip, "y", Strong.easeInOut, 
      Image1movieClip.y, thetargetY, 1.5, true);
```

the following error occurs

```
access of undefined property Strong...
```

however Back and Bounce works here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;
```

without seeing more of your code I would guess it's missing the import statement.

Comment: import fl.transitions.*;
i have imported the above and i thought that it will also import nested packages.. 
That's why, i can not figure out the error. Thanks for help..

Comment: import fl.transitions.easing.*      to import all the transitions inside the easing package. The * will import all the classes inside a specific package.